# git/jenkins TLS issue

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting the following error when Jenkins is trying to clone a repo

Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://github.com/chkp-lebowits/protego-examples/ HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/chkp-lebowits/protego-examples/': Error -50 setting GnuTLS cipher list starting with +VERS-TLS1.3

(I get similar  on "git push" when i point the pipeline to a local repo to get things started and just want to push after build)

When i run the exact same command manually on the same ubuntu 20.4 VM Jenkins is deployed on, the command goes cleanly.

As you can tell, i used Jenkins Global configuration to make sure it uses the same client i use manually.

What am i missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQhnY.png)

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I presume, that this is something, which happens in a Jenkins build-job - how is that defined?
It sounds like a problem with the SSH-key, but it's hard to say...
BTW - please embed images in your questions - it's easier to understand, when you can see both it and the question at the same time...

Comment: thanks re the advice. as it happens right now the error shows up in the webui itself when you create a new pipeline and merely paste the repo's URL as the SCM source. I have similar errors whenever I need any git interaction with github, which i put as steps in the pipeline itself. I'll see these in the console output.

Comment: > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/chkp-lebowits/protego-examples.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/chkp-lebowits/protego-examples.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/chkp-lebowits/protego-examples.git/': Error -50 setting GnuTLS cipher list starting with +VERS-TLS1.3

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on a fresh install of Jenkins on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Using Github API with PAT-based credentials. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with git or github, but with your local configuration. You’ve set GIT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST or the http.sslCipherlList to something your currently used version of gnutls does not support. When git then tells libcurl to tell gnutls to use this cipher list, gnutls tells curl that it can’t do this, and curl feeds this back to git, which is the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by : TLS verion incompatibility. GnuTLS 1.3 is too fasion.
2 ways to fix it:

1. Recompile git against OpenSSL,instead of GnuTLS (What's this???? )
2. use SSH ,such as git@..... to pull your code

[linked issue  here](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/b91tp8/comment/ek2n1xq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

[image]