# Jenkins 128 Error code Unable to access public repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am fairly new to Jenkins
While reading the documents I got stuck at trying to create my first successful build, I followed the "[Getting started](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/)" step by step
when I click save and view the build I get the Error code 128
which after doing some research suggests that I have to do some kind of authentication, I am assuming for SSH but what I don't understand is that the repo is public and does not require an authentication, the documentation simply does not mention anything about github authentication up to the point where we save the pipeline

[My repo](https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI)

```
Branch indexing
Connecting to https://api.github.com with no credentials, anonymous access
Obtained Jenkinsfile from d639281fcf8f6e5dab1cd633a0f7af0727ff7dc5
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/snap/jenkins/2126/workspace/secteam_test_main
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git
 > /usr/bin/git init /var/snap/jenkins/2126/workspace/secteam_test_main # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git/': Error -50 setting GnuTLS cipher list starting with +VERS-TLS1.3

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2102)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:853)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1224)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I added git to the path `/usr/local/bin`

I am running my jenkins server in a Mint OEM VM

Using Python3 3.8.5

The `Jenkinsfile`

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'python:3.8.5' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'python3 app.py initdb'              
                sh 'python3 app.py runserver'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `git clone https://github.com/secteam911/BasicAPI.git` in your shell? Firstly with your user, secondly with the user that runs your Jenkins instance?

Comment: I clone the repo without any issues

Comment: With both? You're using Git 2.25.1. What if you update to [the latest 2.34.0](https://git-scm.com/download/linux)?

Comment: I don't think i am using any credentials because all i did was ``` sudo apt-get install git``` and then cloned the repo to the desktop and it installed that version of git

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62414353/1256452) is a duplicate but has no answer. See also [GitHub support answers](https://github.community/t/git-unable-to-access-error-50-setting-gnutls-cipher-list-starting-with-vers-tls1-3-srp/1885) and [magit issue #152](https://github.com/magit/forge/issues/152).